# State a reason the given function is not a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$f:\Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R$ and $f(x)=\sqrt x$

---

For $\forall x\lt0\in\Bbb R$, $f(x)=\sqrt x\in\Bbb C\notin\Bbb R$

---

Does my answer make sense, or should I elaborate with words?

Comment: Your map isn't well defined.

Comment: @user26857, that was the logic I was attempting to use to disprove the function being a homomorphism.

Comment: What function? There is no function here! (One can't can define $\sqrt x\in\mathbb R$ for $x<0$.)

Comment: That is what I was trying to say to show it is not a homomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some problems with the problem itself. For starters $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ does not make sense with domain and codomain as stated. So we could either extend the codomain to $\mathbb{C}$, or restrict the domain to $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. But now what group are we talking about? Under what operation?

For example, $f:\mathbb{R}_{>0}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ defined by sending $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ (the positive value) is a homomorphism when the domain and codomain are considered as groups under multiplication. So I would suggest looking for reasons why the map is not a homomorphism and not why the mapping itself is maybe problematic as a function.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$ fails. Can you think of an example?

Comment: $x=1$ and $y=-1$. This would prove the function is not a homomorphism. However, is my answer still viable, since it shows that the function fails to map a real number to the set of real numbers?

Comment: No, $x,y $ must be positive. How about $x = y = 1$?

Comment: That would work. I forgot that when we have $f(-x)$, it is equivalent to $-f(x)$, so that would make my approach mistaken.

Comment: @JonSnow You're claiming $f(-x)$ is equivalent to $-f(x)$. Why?